# Can I use VLOOKUP to look up certain date and pull all data needed from that date?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am creating a Gantt Chart for scheduling orders. All my data is from an Access query linked to this Excel Workbook. I have a Data Worksheet that contains all the data I need to show in my Gantt Chart.

I am using VLOOKUP to look up the date and then pull each order in the Data Worksheet under that date and put it into the Scheduling Worksheet. I can't figure out how to pull different orders numbers after the first order number under that date or if it's even possible to do that using VLOOKUP.

[image: Scheduling Worksheet]

[image: Data Worksheet]

Comment: A vlookup will look for a match and not look any further. Using a VLOOKUP as you described would only pull the very first instance of the date's order number.

Comment: @MarkS.I was afraid of that...

Comment: No, you cannot use Vlookup for that. But you can use Power Query to load the data and transform it into the table you show. Or if the data comes from Access anyway, just do a query into Access directly and leave out the nonsensical line for the date. Put it where you need it, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand you correctly, you are trying to match order number based on date and put it in to a chart. From what I have done when VLOOKUP does not work, I would do a match and index. So with that, index the date and match the workorder to that day then a column of values will be output like so.[image]